# Android ListView starting offset?

Tags: java, android, listview, offset

anyone knows how do i change the starting offset of a ListView ?

i mean to make the list view's starting item a different item then number zero

so when you drag down the listview from starting point it will return to the first (custom) starting point item

when i try using ListView.offsetTopAndBottom(x) it gets that effect,
 only its not usable for me because it changes the offset of the entire view (the bottom as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use setSelection() to set the selected item in the list which, in turn, should make sure that item visible.

Comment: yes setSelection() sets the listViews first item,But, i'm trying to anchor a specified offset so that when you pull the listview down it will jump back to that offset.